# Python writing to temporary csv file doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I cannot figure out why this doesn't work.

```
def write_csv(partition):  
  field_names = ['Latitude','Longitude','GPSTimeUTC', 'Speed', 'Bearing']
  with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as keyfile:
    writer = csv.writer(keyfile)
    writer.writerow(field_names)
    for row in partition:
      row = row.asDict()
      row = {key: value for key, value in row.items() if key in field_names}
      print row
      writer.writerow(list(row.values()))
```

My input file is some RDD in the form of list of key/value tuples.I want to create some temp csv file which I will be able to use later on.

Print row gives me something like [47.31709671020508, 79, 3.0, 1542924171526, 8.521432876586914] which is fine.However, if I try to read from my file

```
with open(keyfile.name) as f:
    for line in f:
      print line
```

It does not return me anything(and it doesnt matter if it is inside the previous with clause or not)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Return the instance of the temporary file from write_csv and use the file handle to do your reading, does this help solve the issue?

Comment: Try `for line in f.readlines():`

Comment: Which System do u have? I tried it with windows and python 3.6 and it worked for me

Comment: `print row => [47.31709671020508, 79, 3.0, 1542924171526, 8.521432876586914]` is not fine since row is supposed to be a dict.